# How to VOIP/Voice with my friends in battle log?

Tags: battlefield-4

This used to work with BF3 that you would join in a group with your friends via battlelog and you could voice chat. While nothing has changed on our computers, except installing BF4. How do we chat? we currently can only type to each other (feels like back in the 90's).

Comment: You could always use Skype/Teamspeak/Mumble/BF3 battlelog/squad voice in-game/whatever while BF4 battlelog's is missing

Comment: sure, we used Steam chat for now

Comment: I know you can VOIP chat in game, while in the same squad.  But I will look into this tonight.

Answer (score 2):

This does not exist in the new battlelog as of right now.   If you want to used VOIP, you can IN-Game VOIP system by being in the all in the same squad and by hitting **`Left-Alt`** (by default).

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I tried that worked is:

- Create a group chat and join voice within the battlelog BF3 page...
- Select BF3 at the top of battlelog if your already on the BF4 page
- Switch back to the BF4 page and start playing as normal with private chat.